# Java: Eight-Queen problem matrix won't display the right board

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Sorry if this post isn't very clear, I'm not think straight right now.

I have been struggling with this Eight Queens assignment and can't seem to understand why the two test `BoardState` objects display the same board, but differ in conflict count, with only one of them showing the right board with the right amount of conflicts.

Below is the `Main` class and the `BoardState` class(the latter being used to keep track of data about a given board).

Any help would be much appreciated.

**BoardState Class**

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class BoardState {
    int[][] board;
    int[][] boardReverse;
    int conflictCount;
    
    public BoardState(int[][]arr){
        this.boardReverse=new int[arr[0].length][arr[0].length];
        this.board=arr.clone();

        for(int i=0;i<arr[0].length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j< arr[0].length; j++){
                this.boardReverse[i][j]=this.board[arr[0].length-1-i][j];
            }
        }
        this.conflictCount=updateConflictCount();
    }
    
    public int updateConflictCount(){
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<board[0].length;i++){
            int rowCount=0;
            //horizontal conflict summing
            for(int j=0; j<board[0].length; j++){
                rowCount+=this.board[i][j];
            }
            count+=((rowCount*(rowCount-1))/2);
            //front diagonal conflict summing
        }
        count+=diagonalCount();
        return count;
    }
    
    //adds each sum of the diagonal to an int array
    public int diagonalCount(){
        int count=0;
        int tempSum=0;
        int j=0;
        int k;
        int i=0;
        //back diagonals

        for(i=0; i< board[0].length; i++){
            k=i;
            j=i;
            i=0;
            while(j>=0){
                tempSum+=this.board[j][i];
                j--;
                i++;
            }
            count+=(tempSum*(tempSum-1))/2;
            tempSum=0;
            i=k;
        }

        for(i=1; i< board[0].length; i++){
            k=i;
            j=board[0].length-1;
            while(i<=board[0].length-1){
                tempSum+=this.board[j][i];
                j--;
                i++;
            }
            count+=(tempSum*(tempSum-1))/2;
            tempSum=0;
            i=k;
        }

        //front diagonals
        for(i=0; i< board[0].length; i++){
            k=i;
            j=i;
            i=0;
            while(j>=0){
                tempSum+=this.boardReverse[j][i];
                j--;
                i++;
            }
            count+=(tempSum*(tempSum-1))/2;
            tempSum=0;
            i=k;
        }

        for(i=1; i< board[0].length; i++){
            k=i;
            j=board[0].length-1;
            while(i<=board[0].length-1){
                tempSum+=this.boardReverse[j][i];
                j--;
                i++;
            }
            count+=(tempSum*(tempSum-1))/2;
            tempSum=0;
            i=k;
        }

        return count;
    }

    public int[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(int[][] board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public int[][] getBoardReverse() {
        return boardReverse;
    }

    public void setBoardReverse(int[][] boardReverse) {
        this.boardReverse = boardReverse;
    }

    public int getConflictCount() {
        this.setConflictCount(0);
        this.setConflictCount(this.updateConflictCount());
        return conflictCount;
    }

    public void setConflictCount(int conflictCount) {
        this.conflictCount = conflictCount;
    }
    
    public int[][] copyBoard(int[][] arr){
        int[][] copy=new int[arr[0].length][arr[0].length];
        for(int i=0;i<arr[0].length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<arr[0].length; j++){
                copy[i][j]=arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        return copy;
    }

    public ArrayList<BoardState> getMoves(){
        //get possible moves in each column
        ArrayList<BoardState> prospectives= new ArrayList<BoardState>();
        prospectives.clear();
        int k;
        BoardState temp= new BoardState(this.getBoard().clone());
        for(int i=0; i<board[0].length; i++){
            temp.setBoard(this.copyBoard(this.board));
            temp.setConflictCount(this.getConflictCount());
            for(k=0; k<board[0].length; k++){
                if(board[k][i]==1){
                    temp.board[k][i]=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int j=0; j<board[0].length; j++){
                temp.board[j][i]=1;
                if(temp.getConflictCount()<this.getConflictCount()){
                    prospectives.add(new BoardState(temp.getBoard()));
                }
                temp.board[j][i]=0;
            }
            temp.board[k][i]=1;
        }
        return prospectives;
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    int restarts = 0;
    int stateChanges = 0;

    static ArrayList<BoardState> NeighborList = new ArrayList<BoardState>();

    public void DisplayBoard(int[][] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void initQueens(int[][] arr) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
            arr[rand.nextInt(8)][i] = 1;
        }
    }

    public static BoardState initBoard(int[][] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        initQueens(arr);
        return new BoardState(arr);
    }

    public static BoardState findMaxima(BoardState state) {
        BoardState using = state;
        while (true) {
            ArrayList<BoardState> temp = new ArrayList<BoardState>(using.getMoves());
            if (temp.size() == 0) {
                //send to solution testing
                return new BoardState(using.board);
            }

            System.out.println(using.getConflictCount());
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
                if (temp.get(i).getConflictCount() < using.getConflictCount()) {
                    using = temp.get(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        Main testObj = new Main();

        int[][] board = new int[8][8];
        BoardState current = initBoard(board);
        BoardState current2 = initBoard(board);
        BoardState test = new BoardState(board);
        testObj.DisplayBoard(current.board);
        System.out.println("Conflicts: " + current.updateConflictCount());
        System.out.println();
        testObj.DisplayBoard(current2.board);
        System.out.println("Conflicts: " + current2.updateConflictCount());

        /* non-debugging code
        BoardState finalState;
        while (true) {
             finalState=findMaxima(current);
            if (finalState.getConflictCount()==0) {
                break;
            }
            testObj.restarts++;
            System.out.println(testObj.restarts);
            current=testObj.initBoard(board);
        }

        testObj.DisplayBoard(finalState.board);
        System.out.println(testObj.stateChanges);
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [tour]. Please aim to reduce your code to a [mcve] - it takes a lot of time to read thru a wall of code.  Read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question and come back to [edit] it with those improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that current and current2 use the same array (board). And in initBoard() you set randomly queens.
So you first create the board, compute your conflict count, then you overwrite the board and compute another different conflict count and then you print the board twice. But since the original board of current is overwritten you have to identical boards and different conflict count.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. thank you so much. I tried again with new int[][] as parameters and it seems to work

Comment: @CO2blast if this answer solves your problem, make sure you mark it as resolved.  If not, upvote the answer to mark it as useful (if it is)